# Intersecting lattices with surfaces in R^d

Tags: nt.number-theory, mg.metric-geometry, lattices, euclidean-lattices

Let us fix some bounded surface $S\subset \mathbb{R}^d$. Let $x_1,\ldots, x_m$ be some non-zero vectors in $\mathbb{R}^d$. I am interested is the maximum number of points that the lattice $L_m=\{\sum k_ix_i: k_i\in \mathbb{Z}\}$ can intersect $S$. Thus I would like to fix $S$ and then pick the worst case for the $x_i'$s. Even the case of the sphere is of interest. What sufficient conditions could one give to guarantee that the intersection is finite?

Comment: Well, in the case of the sphere there are lattices intersecting it in an arbitrarily large number of points.

Comment: @AntoineLabelle could you elaborate more? So for n=1 there are 2 points, for n=d=2 taking $x_1, x_2$ at an angle $\alpha \neq 0$ and it seams one could get an upper bound of the form $C\alpha$. So maybe if the determinant of the lattice is non-zero, one could get a finite bound for all $n$ depending just on the determinant and $n,d$?

Comment: There's a formula for the number of integer points on the circle of radius $\sqrt{n}$, and it is unbounded. Hence for suitable $n$ the lattice $\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\mathbb{Z}^2$ can intersect the unit circle in arbitrarily many  points. Did I understood your question correctly?

Comment: @AntoineLabelle so in your example the number of points will be some concrete function of $n$, so it is bounded in terms of $n$. So when I said bounded, it by no means implies uniformly bounded. It is a finite quantity when you fix S, n, d (for S with a certain condition, which I am trying to figure out). So the bound is some function of all of the parameters, but never infinite for fixed values of the parameters. So in your example, assume that $n=4k+1$. The number of points on the circle will be $4$ times the number of divisors of $n$ and so the number of lattice points will be $<n^{1/2}$.

Comment: What is $n$ for a general lattice?

Comment: @AntoineLabelle I used $n$ in your example, so not sure what your question means.

Comment: You say that you want to find bounds in terms of $n$. But if you fix $n$ in my example you fix the lattice, so clearly the number of intersection points is finite. I'm not sure what you want your bounds to depend on in the general case.